# CapacitorHttp send empty file from android/ios

Tags: android, ios, http, multipartform-data, capacitor

I use capacitorJS 4 and make requests using plugin CapacitorHttp.
I get file from , get formData
`const data = new FormData() data.append('file', e.target.files[0])`
but when I send request, "data" is empty.

Request:
`const { data } = await CapacitorHttp.post({ method, url: encodeURI(getters.getUrlApi + url), data: formData, headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': auth, 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data' } })`

In console on device (eruda plugin) I see formData

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgYJZ.jpg)

Screen from AndroidStudio where "data" is empty
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6V4C.png)

What is ploblem?

I tried used @capacitor-community/http, with "request" and "uploadFile" methods. I tried sent in base64 format. I tried to updated the Capacitor to version 5. I tried sent from http and https (localhost:8080).
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and why it doesn't work, what's the problem. It is available on both android and iOS. I can't use axios because I need to use cookies

Answer (score 0):

I registered instead of 'localhost', the backend address by adding the subdomain 'app', and returned back 'axios' (cookies using axios began to work on the subdomain) instead of 'capacitotHttp',
On iOS, I installed plugins for cookies using axios:
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-inject-cookie

Now the form Data is not empty when sending